# How to get the original file extension after INFLATE?

Tags: c++, zlib, compression, inflate

I'm using zlib and C++ to compress/decompress files.

I can now deflate any file and put it to .z extension. But when inflating .z file I have to manually put the needed extension. Inflating works as it should and I can easily inflate .z file to stdout or file.

I 've read [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) but couldn't manage, how to solve my problem. I suppose I need to dig the archive's header for this information?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I guess you've dropped original extension while compressing. I.e. you should compress into file.ext.z, not to file.z.

Comment: @Matt, true. I've cut the original extension :) Your hack is really nice, but is there any other way?

Comment: It's not really a hack. Think of those .tar.gz files. Zilb has no original fileinfo inside compressed stream. You have to deal with this yourself. Unix-way is tar. But you may choose some other options if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

The zlib library will compress and decompress both zlib and gzip streams. zlib streams have very compact header and trailer with no provision to store file name information. The gzip header and trailer on the other hand can store a file name, which can be used when decompressing. You should read the [zlib documentation](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) to see how to use the gzip format, and how to process the gzip header.